# Trying to 'import cv2' but it throws Fatal Python error

Tags: python, opencv, path

Tying to run this simple graphic program "QuiltRotation.py" in VisualStudio2022:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\FuzzyLogicUserName\\Documents\\FuzzyImage.png")

(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
center = (h/2, w/2)
scale = 1.0

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(CENTER, angle, scale)
rotate = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (h, w))

cv2.imshow("ShowTheImage", rotate)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when I run this program in Visual Studio, it throws this Fatal Error:

*"Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec*

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'*

*Current thread 0x00001054 (most recent call first):*

*Press any key to continue . . ."*

Steps taken to resolve this error:

- Putting the cursor over the 'cv2' shows this suggestion from VisualStudio:

  [Need to resolve this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfxRB.png)
- Then I uninstalled previous python version and opencv package, rebooted.
- performed clean installation of python 3.12.1 from python.org

  - clicked Admin box
  - clicked default location
- installed pip, then upgraded it to 23.3.1
- executed '>>>pip install opencv-contrib-python'.  Installation of 4.8.1.78 was successful.
- '>>>pip list' now shows:

Package               Version

---

numpy                 1.26.2

opencv-contrib-python 4.8.1.78

pip                   23.3.2

When I attempt to run the python program above, it throws the Fatal Python error.

But if I use a terminal window and type '>>>import cv2', it simply does a carriage return (e.g., accepts the command and does not throw an error)

I assume that 'opencv' is successfully installed (?) since an error was not thrown for 'import cv2'

**So, if opencv was installed correctly, then how can I get my python program to accept the 'import cv2' command?**

I suspected this could be a path problem, so here's the paths to python, opencv, and my program:

- C:\Users\FuzzyLogicUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\**python**.exe
- C:\Users\FuzzyLogicUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\**python**.exe
- C:\Users\FuzzyLogicUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\**cv2**\_*init*_.py
- C:\Users\FuzzyLogic\source\repos\QuiltRotation.py\QuiltRotation.py.py

Are all these paths correct?

When I look at the Environment Variables, click Paths, I see these:

- C:\Users\FuzzyLogicUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\
- C:\Users\FuzzyLogicUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\
- C:\Users\FuzzyLogicUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.12
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Comment: How did you install opencv? `pip install opencv-python`?

Comment: Why are you  using double back slash "C:\\Users\\FuzzyLogicUserName....  the correct way ...C:\Users\FuzzyLogicUser\AppData\ And if not then use lower character 'r' like this: r'C:\Users\

Comment: Tino D - yes, I used pip.  See above: "executed '>>>pip install opencv-contrib-python'. Installation of 4.8.1.78 was successful."

Comment: Toyota Supra - the double backslash was left over from another program.  I'll correct it.  I do not believe this is related to the import cv2 error I'm struggle with now.